# Sum of K elements in array that equates to N

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, recursion

Given an array say nums = { 1,2,5,3,6,-1,-2,10,11,12}, using max no of elements (say maxNums=3)
find the elements whose sum (say sum =10) = K

so if maxNums to be used = 3 
    sum to find = 10
the the answer is

```
    {1  3  6}    
    {1  -1  10}
    {1  -2  11}
    {2  5  3}
    {2  -2  10}
    {5 6 -1}
    {-1  11}
    {-2  12}
    {10}
```

I wrote a recursive function which does the job. **How do I do it without recursion?**
and/or with less memory ?

```
class Program
{
        static Int32[] nums = { 1,2,5,3,6,-1,-2,10,11,12};
        static Int32 sum = 10;
        static Int32 maxNums = 3;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Int32[] arr = new Int32[nums.Length];
            CurrentSum(0, 0, 0, arr);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Print(Int32[] arr)
        {
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] != 0)
                    Console.Write("  "   +arr[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        public static void CurrentSum(Int32 sumSoFar, Int32 numsUsed, Int32 startIndex, Int32[] selectedNums)
        {
            if ( startIndex >= nums.Length  || numsUsed > maxNums)
            {
                if (sumSoFar == sum && numsUsed <= maxNums)
                {
                    Print(selectedNums);
                }                    
                return;
            }

                       **//Include the next number and check the sum**
                    selectedNums[startIndex] = nums[startIndex];
                    CurrentSum(sumSoFar + nums[startIndex], numsUsed+1, startIndex+1, selectedNums);

                    **//Dont include the next number**
                    selectedNums[startIndex] = 0;
                    CurrentSum(sumSoFar , numsUsed , startIndex + 1, selectedNums);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is not clear as well as the language you're using

Comment: I am using C# as the language

Comment: This is the **subset-sum problem**; it is an extremely famous problem. There is an enormous amount of literature on how to solve it, though it is important to note that **in its most general form it cannot be solved quickly.** (That is, there is a fast solution iff P==NP, and P almost certainly does not equal NP.)

Comment: What is min and max possible value of elements inside array?

Comment: you don't care about run time and you just want to get rid of recursion?   in this case, i will give you a hint.  consider what is being stored on the stack.  pull it out and put it into an array.  observe that your recursion does not go deeper than maxNums levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You function looks fine but possible a bit optimize:

```
class Program
{
    static Int32[] nums = { 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, -1, -2, 10, 11, 12 };
    static Int32 sum = 10;
    static Int32 maxNums = 3;
    static Int32[] selectedNums = new Int32[maxNums];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CurrentSum(0, 0, 0);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Print(int count)
    {
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" " + selectedNums[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void CurrentSum(Int32 sumSoFar, Int32 numsUsed, Int32 startIndex)
    {
        if (sumSoFar == sum && numsUsed <= maxNums)
        {
            Print(numsUsed);
        }

        if (numsUsed >= maxNums || startIndex >= nums.Length)
            return;

        for (int i = startIndex; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            // Include i'th number
            selectedNums[numsUsed] = nums[i];
            CurrentSum(sumSoFar + nums[i], numsUsed + 1, i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also I fixed a bug in your function.
It fails on following testcase:

```
{10, 2, -2}
Sum = 10
K = 3
```

Your functions returns only `{10}` instead of `{10} and {10, 2, -2}`

Comment: you're close.  why don't you just get rid of the recursion altogether.  clearly you're not *really* using the stack for anything.

Comment: He need lesser memory usages. In this problem not used deep recursion because time of working is 2^N. Where N max possible deep of recursion, in fact this is not used a lot of memory. Provided by me algo possible a bit improve via use sumSoFar and numsUSed as global variables.

Answer (score 1):

And the Haskell solution...

```
import Data.List
listElements max_num k arr = 
  filter (\x -> sum x == k && length x == max_num) $ subsequences arr
```

*Main> listElements 3 10 [1,2,5,3,6,-1,-2,10,11,12]
[[2,5,3],[1,3,6],[5,6,-1],[1,-1,10],[2,-2,10],[1,-2,11]]