# Can it be possible to compute in linear time O(n) or O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find an approach in O(n) or O(n log n) to return the output in the following case. If i have a set with n elements and i need to find the minimum set of numbers in the set which adds up to the number given.

For example,
A=[0,9,1,2,5,4], If i were given with q=6, then my possible combinations are: (2+4), (1+5) and should return null if no proper subset is found?, This is not an homework question, I just want to learn for good programming approaches.

Comment: [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: looks like you have to try out every possible combination.. cannot be done in O(n)..
but maybe a multithreaded version could be faster

Comment: if you're interested, have a look at matroids and greedy algorithms;)

Comment: Please refer to my question that has the solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575931/sum-of-k-elements-in-array-that-equates-to-n

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575931/sum-of-k-elements-in-array-that-equates-to-n

Answer (score 1):

The general problem is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem.

To the best of our knowledge there are no polynomial-speed algorithms which solve the problem and it is believed that none exist.  However, some good approximation methods exist.

Comment: There is the pseudo polynomial algorithm, which is what usually tested in programming competition.